# How to use ReactJS and Babel with JSON API in Golang

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, babeljs

I have a simple REST API written in Golang. Now I want to have an async UI and wanted to go with ReactJS + Babel or Typescript + fetch() to get data from my JSON api. Don't want nodejs or anything else.

Most of the examples require nodejs and I can't find something to have as an example to build the UI. Could someone help with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out finally.

Basically using babel-standalone helped a lot. And using axios for fetching data was easy enough.